# Don't make tags clickable (or new window) on ask a question!

Tags: discussion, user-interface

I am just about to make my first question on cooking.stackexchange.com and I had a heart-stopping second!

I wrote the question, and I had to choose tags, (I am still picking now) I wanted advice and wrote this, but no suggestions came up apart from what I typed in above it...

[image]

I have written a few questions across the sites and maybe it is the colour scheme, or just me (not sure), but I thought I had to click it (in the same way as if you type the first few characters, then click...) it navigated away from the page! I clicked back and my question was saved, but, there was no prompt or warning.

What do you think?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. we auto-save drafts for questions and answers (one draft per) -- turn your PC off and your composed question or answer will be there when you navigate back..
2. there is a javascript alert on navigating away after you've composed a post.. verified myself on cooking. I typed some stuff in the ask box, entered a tag, then clicked on the tag.

[image: you have started writing or editing a post]

Comment: Very good point RE: Autosave, as for that prompt, I am using Chrome and it never came up (and you are right, it usually does when I click links :S )

Comment: FFS, now it does come up... I feel like an idiot... but thanks! marking as answer.